# Auto Complete drop down HTML not appearing in Chrome Inspect

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, testing, google-chrome-devtools, web-testing

[image]

In the above HTML page. A drop-down appears. The problem I am facing is I am unable to see the corresponding HTML appearing in the Inspect tab. I also checked the **Break on subtree modification** on some nodes in the inspect panel. But nothing happens. The URL is accessible 
 on internet. Any ideas what to do about it?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how exactly you've reached the conclusion that the "drop down" you're seeing here is part of the DOM and not painted by the browser itself at a higher level? *Why* would you want the browser to paint this into the DOM where sites could read its contents and exfiltrate them? As a user, would you want your autocomplete data be able to be read and stored by external sites/ad networks without your explicit approval? Why exactly do you need access to this menu from the DOM? [ask]

Comment: @esqew I am trying to write a test for this website using Selenium. 
How can I verify programmatically that the dropdown has appeared?
I understand the dropdown may not be part of the DOM. 
In that case, I cannot use the `visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className(""))` thing because the drop down will not be part of the DOM

Comment: "*How can I verify programmatically that the dropdown has appeared?*" Why would you need to test this when this popup is provided by the user agent itself and not anything having to do with the site being tested? Can you elaborate a bit on that? Have you considered users who have this feature disabled (themselves, or by their domain admin's GPO policies) for security/privacy reasons? At the end of the day, you have severely limited options as a well-architected browser should not expose this data to outside processes.

Comment: @esqew, I got your point. You mean the drop-down that I see could be part of the browser and not DOM. So it's something that my chrome is automatically generating and has nothing to do with the website, so that is why I cannot see it in the inspect panel, which shows the complete DOM tree. Is there any other way to verify if the drop is generated by the chrome or by the website?